# webpack dev server did not output the file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a directory like this

[image]

I have a webpack file like this

```
module.exports = {
    env : 'production',
    debug: !prod,
    devtool: !prod ? 'eval' : '',
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets/bundle/entries'),
    entry: [
      'webpack/hot/dev-server',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      './feed.js'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'main.js'
    },
    plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        React: "react"
    })
  ]
}
```

Why when I hit http://localhost:3000/main.js nothing is found? In webpack I did see webpack got the feed.js, maybe my output path is wrong? No right? publicPath is set to '/', so I actually can get bundled feed.js as main.js in http://localhost:3000/main.js

Comment: Webpack listens on `8080`, why are you trying `3000`?

Comment: @jiyinyiyong I solved this problem already, now I have this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240027/webpack-multiple-entries-in-a-directory