# webpack multiple entries in a directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

```
context: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets/bundle/js'),
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './*.js'
  ]
```

Is above code even valid? instead of specifying every single file like

```
context: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets/bundle/entries'),
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './abc.js',
    './def.js'
  ]
```

how can I include entire folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you use the entire folder?

if you want entire folder , you can use `glob` npm module

As explained : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370

```
var glob = require("glob");
// ...
entry: glob.sync("./src/scripts/*.js")
```

but webpack is not recommended entire folder, the entry value should resolve to a specific file, or a list of specific files.

Comment: I got this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240246/wildcard-entry-point-usng-glob-on-webpack-got-error

Comment: @JessicaRobertson - the exact error? - if you're globbing, you should be able to then pass that array of entries into webpack as an entry point

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by your own, as the webpack.config.js is just a node.js module and allows to execute any code.
[Wildcards in entry points](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370)

Answer (score 0):

Webpack uses entry point to resolve the reference to generate the bundle. you can define multiple entry point based on the number of bundle needed.  you  should not be adding entire folder as entry point, it means you want bundle of each file inside the folder, which webpack does not recommend.

> https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html